# Что должен знать Web разработчик на python?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

То что надо знать html, css, javascript, mysql это само собой, а что ещё?
 1. С какими библиотеками надо/желательно работать.
 2. Фреймворки? (плюсы, минусы, стоит ли вообще использовать), хотелось бы услышать отзывы о django.
 3. Нужно ли знать какие-либо ещё языки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В принципе нужно всё названное вами + Django. Нужные библиотеки - это уже зависит от того, что будете делать. Лично я всегда заменяю стандартную админку на grappelly, докидываю debugtoolbar. Ну а дальше - уже зависит от конкретного случая. В любом случае придётся испортировать всякие сторонние приложения, а в этом нет ничего сложного.
Ах да, ещё было бы классно знать mercurial, ну и принцип virtualenv(хотя это уже на любителя).
Охарактеризую django, как этот фреймворк для меня:
 1. Прост в освоении
 2. Большое число сторонних приложений
 3. Обширная встроенная библиотека
Вроде ничего не забыл :)

Answer (score 2):

Стоит уточнить что вы имеете ввиду под **web-разработчиком**, если просто писать сайтики без высокой нагрузки то:

1. Фреймворки **Django** или **Pylons**(а если он то было бы не плохо знать SQLAlchemy) или **Turbogears**.
2. Иметь опыт работы с linux, связанный с развертыванием сайта на выбранном вами фреймворке.
3. Как вы уже сказали, знать javascript.

Кстати:

> mysql это само собой

не обязательно, можно знать любую другую субд. А вот SQL знать стоит.

Если вы хотите занимать разработкой высоко нагруженных веб систем то нужно смотреть в сторону Twisted или Tornado(я как понимаю написан на twisted).